# Get plain text from child tags

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using [highlight.js](https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js) to input a custom CSS code, but that library add span tags to the text I want to get

for example

```
<pre>
<code class="language-css hljs" contenteditable="true" id="css-code">
<span class="token selector"><span class="hljs-selector-class">.spacer-line</span></span> <span class="token punctuation">{</span>
    <span class="token property"><span class="hljs-attribute">border-bottom-width</span></span><span class="token punctuation">:</span> <span class="hljs-number">20px</span><span class="token punctuation">;</span>
    <span class="token property"><span class="hljs-attribute">width</span></span><span class="token punctuation">:</span> <span class="hljs-number">50%</span><span class="token punctuation">;</span>
    <span class="token property"><span class="hljs-attribute">border-color</span></span><span class="token punctuation">:</span> black<span class="token punctuation">;</span>
<span class="token punctuation">}</span>
</code>
</pre>
```

the plain text for that is:

```
.spacer-line { border-bottom-width: 20px; width: 50%; border-color: black; }
```

**I need to get this.**
how can I get it?

**UPDATE**

for any reason if I use this code:

```
let value = document.querySelector('pre');
console.log(value.textContent);
```

I get the pre tag and the code tag but without span tags
value result:

```
<pre class=" language-css"><code class="language-css hljs" contenteditable="true" id="css-code"></code>
</pre>
```

**and a blank value for textContent**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select the element and get the text content of the element using `innerText` or `textContent`:

```js
console.log(document.querySelector('pre').textContent.trim())
```

```html
<pre>
<code class="language-css hljs" contenteditable="true" id="css-code">
<span class="token selector"><span class="hljs-selector-class">.spacer-line</span></span> <span class="token punctuation">{</span>
    <span class="token property"><span class="hljs-attribute">border-bottom-width</span></span><span class="token punctuation">:</span> <span class="hljs-number">20px</span><span class="token punctuation">;</span>
    <span class="token property"><span class="hljs-attribute">width</span></span><span class="token punctuation">:</span> <span class="hljs-number">50%</span><span class="token punctuation">;</span>
    <span class="token property"><span class="hljs-attribute">border-color</span></span><span class="token punctuation">:</span> black<span class="token punctuation">;</span>
<span class="token punctuation">}</span>
</code>
</pre>
```

Comment: For any reason, queryselector give me the tags without anything inside, I edited my question

Comment: @AndréCuellarAvaroma, as the code example gives the expected output, I guess there could be some thing different in your dev environment that causes the issue but no idea what thar could be.